# Binary search through strings

Tags: python, binary-search

I'm relatively new to python(3.3) and I'm just trying to do a binary search through a list of words, and cant figure out how to fix my operand types when it comes down to looping through the indices... I continue to get the TypeError. Cant figure out any way around it

```
def find(L, target):
    start = 0
    end = len(L) - 1

    while start <= end: 
        middle = (start + end)// 2 
        midpoint = L[middle]
        if midpoint > target:
            end = midpoint - 1
        elif midpoint < target:
            start = midpoint + 1
        else:
            return midpoint
```

I'm calling the function as so:

L = ["Brian", "Meg", "Peter", "Joe", "Stewie", "Lois"]

find(L, "Joe")

Comment: binary search only works on sorted lists

Comment: `midpoint` is a string. What should `midpoint - 1` do?

Comment: @FernandoMatsumoto might be a typo. I think he meant `middle - 1`, `middle + 1`.

Comment: To do a successful binary search on an array, the data in the array must be in sorted order.  The entries for all except Brian are out of position — the sequence should be Brian, Joe, Lois, Meg, Peter, Stewie.

Comment: @jianweichuah I think Fernando is pointing out the bug.

Comment: @jianweichuah You are probably right, but that's still the cause of the `TypeError` he mentioned. Of course, as mentioned by others that's not the bigger problem.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure why the format of the question came out so inaccurate, I thought I copied the code down right. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your logic seems fine, except for the **input** and the bug with **incrementing and decrementing midpoint instead of middle**.

```
def find(L, target):
    start = 0
    end = len(L) - 1

    while start <= end:
        middle = (start + end)/ 2
        midpoint = L[middle]
        if midpoint > target:
            end = middle - 1
        elif midpoint < target:
            start = middle + 1
        else:
            return midpoint

L = ["Brian", "Joe", "Lois", "Meg", "Peter", "Stewie"] # Needs to be sorted.

print find(L, "Peter")
```

Comment: What if you try to find a string tha doesn't exist? What is returned?

Comment: @cricket_007 None. Not sure what the OP's use case is

Comment: It should be `int((start + end) / 2)`

Answer (score 2):

```
def find(L, target):
    start = 0
    end = len(L) - 1
    while start <= end:
        middle = (start + end)// 2
        midpoint = L[middle]
        if midpoint > target:
            end = middle - 1
        elif midpoint < target:
            start = middle + 1
        else:
            return midpoint

    L = ["Brian", "Joe", "Lois", "Meg", "Peter", "Stewie"]
    L = sorted(L)
    print(find(L, "Lois"))
```

As pointed out by others, use middle instead of midpoint

And to optimally use **binary search**, sort the list first

Comment: `sorted(L)` returns a new sorted list with the elements of `L`. Either use `L = sorted(L)` or `L.sort()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def binarySearchOnString(arr, x):
        l = 0
        r = len(arr) - 1
        while (l <= r): 
            m = (l + r) // 2 
            if (arr[m] == x): 
                return m
            elif (arr[m] < x): 
                l = m + 1
            else: 
                r = m - 1
        return -1  #   If element is not found  then it will return -1
```